# Error for Oracle Driver for DB server 10g and Jboss 4.2.3 application server

Tags: jboss

the error is like 
Apparently wrong driver class specified for URL: class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
I am using ojdbc14.jar which is the latest jar for oracle driver. The DB server is Oracle 10g. I am using spring framework and refereing the jndi name defined in oracle-ds under jboss installation directory.
I dont know why this error is coming. 
kindly help me to resolve this issue

Comment: It's impossible to help out if you don't supply more info. Like errormessages, stacktraces, logfileentries and maybe even config files (oracle-ds.xml).

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem. In my case I can work it out by changing the Replace JNDI data source with Apache Data Source. I am not sure this will work on your environtment. Somehow the spring JNDI could not pick up the JDBC driver class. My database is an Informix database. I hope it helped.

JNDI version:

```
 <bean id="lmsDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiName">
    <value>java:comp/env/smsifmx</value> 
</property>
 </bean>
```

Apache Data Source version:

```
<bean id="lmsDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url">
    <value>jdbc:informix-sqli://<ip_to_your_db>:<db_port>/<server_name>:INFORMIXSERVER=<db_name></value>
    </property>
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value><db_user></value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value><db_password></value>
    </property>
</bean>
```